# Windows startup errors/GRUB "gone"

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, grub

My problems: Windows 7 is not working and GRUB is "gone". This is what's happend:

Note: my OS is in Norwegian so I tried to translate it as good as I can.

- I'm on the internet when there come up a notification that there's only ~2Gb of free space on my hard drive. Windows asks me if there's something I can delete. I choose some folders and delete them.
- I reboot to windows and a startup repair thingy comes up but can't find and/or repair the problem(s).
- In the diagnistics and repair details log is says (among other things) "Boot Manager can't find OS loader". There's 2 failed tests at the bottom: File repair, failed, error code 0xa; Repair of data storage for startup configuration (?), failed, error code: 0x2.
- I found somewhere to try some commands: `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootrec /fixboot`, `bootrec /scanos` and `bootrec /rebuildbcd`, rebooted but nothing had changed. I could still get to Ubuntu from GRUB.
- Then I tried to activate a partition (at the time I didn't know what that would do). I used `diskpart` --> `list disk` --> `select disk X` --> `list partition` --> `select partition X` (here I didn't know which partition to activate, so I made my best guess (the biggest primary), which was wrong. When I rebooted it is said something along: can't find a OS. There was no GRUB.
- I found a lightweight linux (puppy linux), got it on a usb, live booted, activated partition no. 1 on the hard drive, rebooted, and now it goes straight to windows (without the GRUB), to the startup repair program.

This is where I am now. Back to the beginning, only worse.

I don't know what info you'll need, so just ask. Also I'm quite new when it comes to partitioning and the like.

What partition should be active? I've got 2 primary, 1 extended and 2 logical (ubuntu?)

Comment: well, my biggest problem is that windows wont work, and I should probably have googled that a little more, but the last days I have tried to activate another partition so everything works

Answer (score 0):

```
 sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

this repairs GRUB issue like you are having.  Maybe this approach will help.

Comment: but I can't get to Ubuntu, because it's no GRUB. should/can I do it in puppy linux?